# White screen flash with static files, React hydrate and lazy loading

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

I use react-spa-prerender to generate static html files. When a static page loads, the content is initially rendered for a moment, cleared to a white screen, then rendered again.
You can see this by visiting https://www.ezyvue.com.
This is known problem, see this post on the issues page: https://github.com/sPavl0v/react-spa-prenderer/issues/18.
I'm using React 16.13.

This issue only occurs when using lazy loading. I haven't been able to find a workaround.
Here is the React rendering code in my index.js file:

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
if (rootElement.hasChildNodes()) {
  ReactDOM.hydrate(<App />, rootElement);
} else {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
}
```

I also use a React Suspense tag in my App rendering code:

```
render() {
      return (
        <div id='site-root'>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <BrowserRouter>
              <React.Suspense fallback={<div />}>
       ...
```